# strtotime working wrong on two different server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, timezone

I am working on migration process on an application. Moving it to *aws* but facing a wired scenario of time.

http://ooxmonitor.com/phpinfo.php: Correct Date   1520816400

http://ooxmonitor.com/phpinfo.php: wrong date     1520211600

code is same

```
    <?php

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
    echo "<pre>";
    echo strtotime('this week', 1520730000).'</br>';
    echo date('d', strtotime('this week', 1520730000)-6*3600);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    echo date_default_timezone_get();
    ?>
```

My question is if code is same, timezone is same, system date is same then why the difference.

Comment: Probably different versions of php

Comment: can it be the problem? AWS is having php 7 and old is php5.5

Comment: Yup. Take a look at https://3v4l.org/7J6Ru